# Form Validation using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to use form validation using JavaScript, however I don't seem to get any response, not even an alert even though it's there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Example Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function CheckForBlank() {

                if(document.getElementById('name').value="") {
                    alert("enter something valid");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="post" action="2013.php" onsubmit="return CheckForBlank();">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
            Age: <input type="text" name="age" id="age"/>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use comparison (`==` or `===`), not assignment (`=`).

Comment: Remember to also validate this server-side. Javascript validation is easy to bypass.

Answer (score 4):

use === or == for condition checking in javascript.

```
if(document.getElementById('name').value === ""){
   alert("enter something valid");
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't understand, how people upvoted this answer! It's not correct! if you avoid `return false;` form posts back even if there is `alert();`

Comment: i put this code just to make him clear the problem in the condition checking. :-) and i miss the return statement. Now i have editted the answer. Thanks for your correction :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use == for comparison.= is used for assigment

```
if(document.getElementById('name').value == ""){
       alert("enter something valid");
       return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/r2ykavh8/)

Here Your issue is regarding `if` condition only! You must use `==` OR `===` in JavaScript for comparison.

Below is corrected script!

```
function CheckForBlank() {
        if(document.getElementById('name').value=="") {
            alert("enter something valid");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If you remove Or avoid `return false`, form **will** postback Even if Validation fails! So, `return false` means, exiting from function after `if` is must, and which is missed out in another answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `=` that is assignment operator, use `==` comparison operator that's work fine

```
<head>
    <title>Example Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CheckForBlank() {

            if(document.getElementById('name').value=="") {
                alert("enter something valid");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" onsubmit="return CheckForBlank();">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
        Age: <input type="text" name="age" id="age"/>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I've never realised this until now, although if you attach your Javascript to the form submission event, instead of the button submit event; the normal browser verification works (ie. input[type="email], required="required", etc.).

Works in Firefox & Chrome.

```
// jQuery example attaching to a form with the ID form
$(document).on("submit", "#form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log ("Submitted! Now serialise your form and AJAX submit here...");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// 
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const username = document.querySelector('#username');
const email = document.querySelector('#email');
const password = document.querySelector('#password');
const cpassword = document.querySelector('#cpassword');
const mobno = document.querySelector('#mobile');
const dob = document.querySelector('#dob');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    if (!validateInputs()) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

// Attach input event listeners
username.addEventListener('input', () => validateInput(username, 'Username is required'));
email.addEventListener('input', () => validateInput(email, 'Email is required', validateEmail));
password.addEventListener('input', () => validateInput(password, 'Password is required', null, 8));
cpassword.addEventListener('input', () => validateInput(cpassword, 'Confirm password is required', null, null, password));
mobno.addEventListener('input', () => validateInput(mobno, 'Mobile no is required', validateMobile));
dob.addEventListener('input', () => validateInput(dob, 'DOB is required'));

function validateInputs() {
    let success = true;

    success = validateInput(username, 'Username is required') && success;
    success = validateInput(email, 'Email is required', validateEmail) && success;
    success = validateInput(password, 'Password is required', null, 8) && success;
    success = validateInput(cpassword, 'Confirm password is required', null, null, password) && success;
    success = validateInput(mobno, 'Mobile no is required', validateMobile) && success;
    success = validateInput(dob, 'DOB is required') && success;

    return success;
}

function validateInput(element, errorMessage, validationFunction, minLength, compareTo) {
    const value = element.value.trim();
    const inputGroup = element.parentElement;
    const errorElement = inputGroup.querySelector('.error');
    let isValid = true;

    if (value === '') {
        isValid = false;
    } else if (validationFunction && !validationFunction(value)) {
        isValid = false;
    } else if (minLength && value.length < minLength) {
        isValid = false;
    } else if (compareTo && value !== compareTo.value) {
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (!isValid) {
        setError(element, errorMessage);
    } else {
        setSuccess(element);
    }

    return isValid;
}

function setError(element, message) {
    const inputGroup = element.parentElement;
    const errorElement = inputGroup.querySelector('.error');

    errorElement.innerText = message;
    inputGroup.classList.add('error');
    inputGroup.classList.remove('success');
}

function setSuccess(element) {
    const inputGroup = element.parentElement;
    const errorElement = inputGroup.querySelector('.error');

    errorElement.innerText = '';
    inputGroup.classList.add('success');
    inputGroup.classList.remove('error');
}

const validateEmail = (email) => {
    return String(email)
        .toLowerCase()
        .match(
            /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        );
};

const validateMobile = (mobile) => {
    return mobile.length === 10 && /^\d+$/.test(mobile);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="valide.css">
    <script src="validate.js" defer></script>
    <title>Register</title>
    <style>body{
   
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; 
}

#form{
    width:400px;
    margin:20vh auto 0 auto;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:30px;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color:#792099;
}

#form button{
    background-color: #792099;
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid #792099;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:20px 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:20px;
    width:100%;
}

.input-group{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.input-group input{
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid rgb(34,193,195) ;
}

.input-group input:focus{
    outline:0;
}

.input-group .error{
    color:rgb(242, 18, 18);
    font-size:16px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.input-group.success input{
    border-color: #0cc477;
}

.input-group.error input{
    border-color:rgb(206, 67, 67);
}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="" id="form">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" >
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>

               <div class="input-group">
                <label for="mobno">mobileno</label>
                <input type="tel" id="mobile" name="mobile">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                <label for="Dob">date of birth</label>
                <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>


            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
        <script>
            const form = document.querySelector('#form')
const username = document.querySelector('#username');
const email = document.querySelector('#email');
const password = document.querySelector('#password');
const cpassword = document.querySelector('#cpassword');
const mobno = document.querySelector('#mobile');
const dob= document.querySelector('#dob');

form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{

    if(!validateInputs()){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})

function validateInputs(){
    const usernameVal = username.value.trim()
    const emailVal = email.value.trim();
    const passwordVal = password.value.trim();
    const cpasswordVal = cpassword.value.trim();
       const mobileno = mobno.value.trim();
       const dobval=dob.value.trim();
    let success = true

    if(usernameVal===''){
        success=false;
        setError(username,'Username is required')
    }
    else{
        setSuccess(username)
    }

    if(emailVal===''){
        success = false;
        setError(email,'Email is required')
    }
    else if(!validateEmail(emailVal)){
        success = false;
        setError(email,'Please enter a valid email')
    }
    else{
        setSuccess(email)
    }

    if(passwordVal === ''){
        success= false;
        setError(password,'Password is required')
    }
    else if(passwordVal.length<8){
        success = false;
        setError(password,'Password must be atleast 8 characters long')
    }
    else{
        setSuccess(password)
    }

    if(cpasswordVal === ''){
        success = false;
        setError(cpassword,'Confirm password is required')
    }
    else if(cpasswordVal!==passwordVal){
        success = false;
        setError(cpassword,'Password does not match')
    }
    else{
        setSuccess(cpassword)
    }


if(mobileno==''){
       success= false;
        setError(mobno,'mobile no is required')
}
else if(mobileno.length<=10){
    success= false;
        setError(mobno,'its not a valid mob no')
}
  // else if(!validatmob(mobno)){
  //       success = false;
  //       setError(mobno,'Please enter a valid email')
  //   }
else{
    setSuccess(mobno)
}


  if(dobval==''){
       success= false;
        setError(dob,'dob is required')
}
else{
    setSuccess(dob)
}

    return success;
}




function setError(element,message){
    const inputGroup = element.parentElement;
    const errorElement = inputGroup.querySelector('.error')

    errorElement.innerText = message;
    inputGroup.classList.add('error')
    inputGroup.classList.remove('success')
}

function setSuccess(element){
    const inputGroup = element.parentElement;
    const errorElement = inputGroup.querySelector('.error')

    errorElement.innerText = '';
    inputGroup.classList.add('success')
    inputGroup.classList.remove('error')
}

const validateEmail = (email) => {
    return String(email)
      .toLowerCase()
      .match(
        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
      );
  };

  // const validatmob = (mobile) => {
  //   return Integer(mobile)
  //     .toLowerCase()
  //     .match(

  //    /^\+1 \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/ );
  // };
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have done a better way to do form validation using bootstrap. You can take a look at my codepen http://codepen.io/abhilashn/pen/bgpGRw

```js
var g_UnFocusElementStyle = "";
var g_FocusBackColor = "#FFC";
var g_reEmail = /^[\w\.=-]+\@[\w\.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
var g_reCell = /^\d{10}$/;
var g_invalidFields = 0;

function initFormElements(sValidElems) {
 var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
 for(var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
  com_abhi.EVENTS.addEventHandler(inputElems[i], 'focus', highlightFormElement, false);
  com_abhi.EVENTS.addEventHandler(inputElems[i], 'blur', unHightlightFormElement, false);
 }
 /* Add the code for the input elements */
 inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 for(var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
  if(sValidElems.indexOf(inputElems[i].getAttribute('type') != -1)) {
   com_abhi.EVENTS.addEventHandler(inputElems[i], 'focus', highlightFormElement, false);
   com_abhi.EVENTS.addEventHandler(inputElems[i], 'blur', unHightlightFormElement, false);
  }
 }
 
 /* submit handler */
 
 
 com_abhi.EVENTS.addEventHandler(document.getElementById('form1'), 'submit' , validateAllfields, false);
 
 /* Add the default focus handler */
 document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
 
 /* Add the event handlers for validation */
 com_abhi.EVENTS.addEventHandler(document.forms[0].firstName, 'blur', validateFirstName, false);
 com_abhi.EVENTS.addEventHandler(document.forms[0].email, 'blur', validateEmailAddress, false);
 com_abhi.EVENTS.addEventHandler(document.forms[0].address, 'blur', validateAddress, false);
 com_abhi.EVENTS.addEventHandler(document.forms[0].cellPhone, 'blur', validateCellPhone, false);
}

function highlightFormElement(evt) {
 var elem = com_abhi.EVENTS.getEventTarget(evt);
 if(elem != null) {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = g_FocusBackColor;
 }
}

function unHightlightFormElement(evt) {
 var elem = com_abhi.EVENTS.getEventTarget(evt);
 if(elem != null) {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "";
 }
}

function validateAddress() {
 var formField = document.getElementById('address');
 var ok = (formField.value != null && formField.value.length != 0);
 var grpEle = document.getElementById('grpAddress');
 if(grpEle != null) {
  if(ok) {
   grpEle.className = "form-group has-success has-feedback";
   document.getElementById('addressIcon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback";
   document.getElementById('addressErrorMsg').innerHTML = "";
  }
  else  {
   grpEle.className = "form-group has-error has-feedback";
   document.getElementById('addressIcon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback";
   document.getElementById('addressErrorMsg').innerHTML = "Please enter your address";
  }
  return ok;
 }
 
}

function validateFirstName() {
 var formField = document.getElementById('firstName');
 var ok = (formField.value != null && formField.value.length != 0);
 var grpEle = document.getElementById('grpfirstName');
 if(grpEle != null) {
  if(ok) {
   grpEle.className = "form-group has-success has-feedback";
   document.getElementById('firstNameIcon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback";
   document.getElementById('firstNameErrorMsg').innerHTML = "";
  }
  else  {
   grpEle.className = "form-group has-error has-feedback";
   document.getElementById('firstNameIcon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback";
   document.getElementById('firstNameErrorMsg').innerHTML = "Please enter your first name";
  }
  return ok;
 }
}

function validateEmailAddress() {
 var formField = document.getElementById('email');
 var ok = (formField.value.length != 0 && g_reEmail.test(formField.value));
 var grpEle = document.getElementById('grpEmail');
 if(grpEle != null) {
  if(ok) {
   grpEle.className = "form-group has-success has-feedback";
   document.getElementById('EmailIcon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback";
   document.getElementById('emailErrorMsg').innerHTML = "";
  }
  else {
   grpEle.className = "form-group has-error has-feedback";
   document.getElementById('EmailIcon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback";
   document.getElementById('emailErrorMsg').innerHTML = "Please enter your valid email id";
  }
 }
 return ok;
}

function validateCellPhone() {
 var formField = document.getElementById('cellPhone');
 var ok = (formField.value.length != 0 && g_reCell.test(formField.value));
 var grpEle = document.getElementById('grpCellPhone');
 if(grpEle != null) {
  if(ok) {
   grpEle.className = "form-group has-success has-feedback";
   document.getElementById('cellPhoneIcon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback";
   document.getElementById('cellPhoneErrorMsg').innerHTML = "";
  }
  else {
   grpEle.className = "form-group has-error has-feedback";
   document.getElementById('cellPhoneIcon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback";
   document.getElementById('cellPhoneErrorMsg').innerHTML = "Please enter your valid mobile number";
  }
 }
 return ok;
}



function validateAllfields(e) {
 /* Need to do it this way to make sure all the functions execute */
 
 var bOK = validateFirstName();
 bOK &= validateEmailAddress();
 bOK &= validateCellPhone(); 
 bOK &= validateAddress(); 
 

 if(!bOK) {
  alert("The fields that are marked bold and red are required. Please supply valid\n values for these fields before sending.");
  com_abhi.EVENTS.preventDefault(e);
 }
 
 
}

com_abhi.EVENTS.addEventHandler(window, "load", function() { initFormElements("text"); }, false);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <h1 class="text-center">Interactive form validation using bootstrap</h1>
    <form id="form1" action="" method="post" name="form1" class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="margin:10px 0 10px 0">
     <div id="grpfirstName" class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><span class="text-danger">* </span>First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name">
         <span id="firstNameIcon"  class=""></span>
         <div id="firstNameErrorMsg" class="text-danger"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name">
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="grpEmail" class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Email </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
         <span id="EmailIcon"  class=""></span>
           <div id="emailErrorMsg" class="text-danger"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="grpCellPhone" class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Cell Phone </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cellPhone" placeholder="Enter Mobile number">
         <span id="cellPhoneIcon"  class=""></span>
           <div id="cellPhoneErrorMsg" class="text-danger"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="form-group" id="grpAddress">
      <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><span class="text-danger">* </span>Address </label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <textarea id="address" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <span id="addressIcon"  class=""></span>
        <div id="addressErrorMsg" class="text-danger"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      </div>
     </div>
   
  </form>
   </div> <!-- End of row -->
  </div> <!-- End of container -->
```

Please check my codepen to better understand code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Form Validation on Input Click</title>
  <style>
    .error {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="myForm">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" required>
    <span class="error" id="usernameError"></span>

    <br>

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" required>
    <span class="error" id="passwordError"></span>

    <br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    // Function to validate the form
    function validateUsername() {
      let username = document.getElementById('username').value;

      // Simple validation example (you can add more complex validation)
      if (username.trim() === '') {
        document.getElementById('usernameError').innerText = 'Username is required';
        return false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('usernameError').innerText = '';
      }

      return true;
    }

    function validatePassword() {
      let password = document.getElementById('password').value;

      // Simple validation example (you can add more complex validation)
      if (password.trim() === '') {
        document.getElementById('passwordError').innerText = 'Password is required';
        return false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('passwordError').innerText = '';
      }

      return true;
    }

    // Add event listener to the input fields to trigger validation on focus
    document.getElementById('username').addEventListener('focus', validateUsername);
    document.getElementById('password').addEventListener('focus', validatePassword);

    // Add event listener to the form to prevent submission if validation fails
    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (!validateUsername() || !validatePassword()) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function Registration() {
const initialValue = { username: '', email: '', password: '', confirmPassword: '', tnc: false };
const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState(initialValue);
const [formError, setFormError] = useState({})
const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false)
// onchange handler-
const handleInput = (e) => {
const { name, value, type, checked } = e.target;
const inputValue = (type === 'checkbox') ? checked : value;
setFormValue({ ...formValue, [name]: inputValue });
}
// onsubmit handler-
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
setFormError(validate(formValue));
setIsSubmit(true)
}

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(formError).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
        console.log(formValue)
    }
}, [formError, isSubmit, formValue])

// validate form values
const validate = (value) => {
    const error = {}
    let emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    const passwordRegex = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/;


    // username validation
    if (value.username.trim().length === 0) {
        error.username = "username cant be empty*"
    }

    // email validation
    if (!value.email) {
        error.email = "email cant be empty*"
    }
    else if (!emailRegex.test(value.email)) {
        error.email = "email is not valid*"
    }

    // password validation
    if (!value.password) {
        error.password = "Password can't be empty*";
    } else if (!passwordRegex.test(value.password)) {
        error.password = "Password must have at least 8 characters, containing at least one letter, one number, and one special character";
    }

    // confirmPassword validation
    if (!value.confirmPassword) {
        error.confirmPassword = "Confirm Password can't be empty*";
    } else if (!passwordRegex.test(value.confirmPassword)) {
        error.confirmPassword = "Confirm Password must have at least 8 characters, containing at least one letter, one number, and one special character";
    }

    else if (value.password !== value.confirmPassword) {
        error.confirmPassword = "pasword is not matching*"
    }

    // tnc validation
    if (!value.tnc) {
        error.tnc = "Please agree to terms and conditions";
    }

    return error

}
return (
    <>
        {
            (Object.keys(formError).length === 0 && isSubmit) ? <p className='text-center'>register successfully...</p> :
                <div className='container' style={{ width: '450px' }} >
                    <pre>{JSON.stringify(formValue, undefined, 2)}</pre>
                    <form className="p-3 p-md-5 border rounded-2 bg-body-tertiary" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <h3 className='text-center'><u>Registration-Form</u></h3>
                        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="text" name='username' value={formValue.username} className="form-control" id="userInput" placeholder="name@example.com" onChange={handleInput} />
                            <label htmlFor="userInput">Username</label>
                            <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formError.username}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="text" name='email' value={formValue.email} className="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" onChange={handleInput} />
                            <label htmlFor="floatingInput">Email address</label>
                            <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formError.email}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="password" name='password' value={formValue.password} className="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password" onChange={handleInput} />
                            <label htmlFor="floatingPassword">Password</label>
                            <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formError.password}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="password" name='confirmPassword' value={formValue.confirmPassword} className="form-control" id="cPassword" placeholder="confirmPassword" onChange={handleInput} />
                            <label htmlFor="cPassword">confirmPassword</label>
                            <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formError.confirmPassword}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="checkbox mb-3">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="tnc" checked={formValue.tnc} onChange={handleInput} />  agree
                            </label>
                            <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formError.tnc}</p>
                        </div>

                        <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign up</button>
                        <hr className="my-4" />
                        <small className="text-body-secondary">By clicking Sign up, you agree to the terms of use.</small>
                    </form>
                </div>
        }
    </>
)
```

}

export default Registration

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).